# Android web-view-very slow loading

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an android app using the web-view or just the URL of my website.
Unfortunately the created app takes a long time to load(upto 25 secs).
I have tried enabling cache mode, but at that time the cookies get destroyed automatically and thereby it again redirects to login page.

I have been searching the net for answers but couldnt get any thereby posting it here.

Thanks in advance for replying.

Comment: how long spend your mobile browser loading same page?

Comment: When mobile browser cache clear that time takes 10-11 sec max and once cached data it takes max 4-5 sec

Comment: same internet connection? actually the seems reasonable in an old slow device + bad connection, but it is too much for all cases... if cache crashes and without looking at your code, you will need to manually handle login cookies after enabling cache

Comment: maybe your site is very heavy to load... normal browsers download everything using a pool of threads, but your simple WebView surely doesn't... I already developed an app like this, but the result is really poor. My advice? skip this idea...

Comment: This is My pice of code    mWebView.loadUrl("My URL");

            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                                             
                                              findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                          }
                                      }

Comment: Please give me a better suggestion for Webview URL app